# TypeScript generic interface that only has property defined with certain template parameter value

Tags: typescript

I have a generic interface where `T` extends `boolean`.  If `T` extends `true`, I want a property to exist, otherwise, I don't want it to exist.  This interface extends another one, so I can't use a type, and I want not to use multiple interfaces and a union type.

I had hoped that `never` would solve my conundrum.

```ts
interface MyInterface<T extends boolean> extends MyOtherInterface {
    someProp: string;
    conditionalProp: T extends true ? number : never;
}

const cTrue: MyInterface<true> = {
    firstProp: 1,
    someProp: 'foo',
    conditionalProp: 1
  },
  cFalse: MyInterface<false> = { // fails for missing conditionalProp: never
    firstProp: 2,
    someProp: 'bar'
  },
  cAnyTrue: MyInterface<any> = {
    firstProp: 3,
    someProp: 'baz',
    conditionalProp: 3
  },
  cAnyFalse: MyInterface<any> = { // fails for missing conditionalProp: never
    firstProp: 4,
    someProp: 'baz'
  };
```

I also tried using both `void` and `undefined`.  In all three cases, when I instantiated `MyInterface<false>`, it required setting `conditionalProp`.  In the first case, I could assign this to nothing, since its type was `never`.

Like I implied earlier, there is a verbose workaround.

```ts
interface MyInterfaceTrue extends MyOtherInterface {
    someProp: string;
    conditionalProp: number;
}

interface MyInterfaceFalse extends MyOtherInterface {
    someProp: string;
}

type MyInterface<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? MyInterfaceTrue : MyInterfaceFalse;
```

Here's the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-MmOwRwKCOgNBhAAQRA6HVYe1qis6H1caNCbNDoAzKmfHa-pm4AAvN02z0LVp-Bt57yF4shjXPcPyCvF6uG2t0RNkgAszZJbazXYDIiAA).

Comment: I dont know if I understood your question correctly but you may want to take a look at the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types) type

Comment: `Exclude` or more likely `Omit` works for excluding a property in a `type`, but not for a property on an interface.

Comment: I see, So basically you want `MyInterface<true>` to have the signature `{ firstProp: number, someProp: string, conditionalProp: number  }` and `MyInterface<false>` to have the signature `{ firstProp: number, someProp: string }`

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If property names are not statically known then you can't use a single interface; if a property either exists or does not exist based on a condition, you pretty much have to use a union type.  I don't really see why it matters to you, though... if you can edit your code to show a use case where a type alias doesn't work for some reason it might help.

Comment: This was more for my edification than anything else.  I spend so much time writing type stuff that compiles to nothing, that I often wonder if I actually save any time over writing JavaScript.  If I know how to minimize that effort, it saves more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Workaround

```
// The definition of the type with all the properties
interface _Data {
  always: number;
  sometimes: string;
}

// Conditionally exclude the properties if "true" or "false" was passed.
type Data<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? Omit<_Data, "sometimes"> : _Data;

/*
 * Tests
 */

const forTrue: Data<true> = {
  always: 0,
  // sometimes: "" => Error
};

const forFalse: Data<false> = {
  always: 0,
  sometimes: ""
}
```

This solution uses a typedef but you can use a type and an interface almost interchangeably.

---

#### Making things a little nicer

To make this whole thing a little nicer to work with I would suggest extracting the process of "conditionally extracting properties" into a separate type that can be reused.

```
type ConditionallyOmit<Condition extends boolean, T, K extends keyof T> = Condition extends true ? Omit<T, K> : T;
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
type Data<T extends boolean> = ConditionallyOmit<T, _Data, "sometimes">
```

You can of course inline the original definition:

```
type Data<T extends boolean> = ConditionallyOmit<T, {
  always: number;
  sometimes: string;
}, "sometimes">
```

Which would make it as DRY as it gets

---

#### Why you need another type.

I am quite sure that you currently cant do this with only one interface.

I was thinking about approaching this problem by extending a type that would conditionally include a type or `{}` - Something along the lines of this:

```
type TrueOrEmpty<Condition extends boolean, T> = Condition extends true ? {} : T;
```

This would give you either `T` or `{}`, so it would conditionally add either `{}` which would do nothing, or include the properties you would have liked to be in there - depending on what you pass in.

I would then have used this to extend the interface, like:

```
interface Data<T extends boolean>
  // Properties you only want when you pass true
  extends TrueOrEmpty<T, { sometimes: string }>
{
    // Properties you always want to have
    always: number
}
```

But this gives you the following error:

`An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.`

And there is no way around that error: Typescript can not know what to include statically so it disallows it.

Comment: That works, but I was really hoping to do it with just a single interface (and no type).

Comment: I dont think it is possible with just one interface - Give me a few minutes to think about things though. What you can do to make this a little nicer is extract the logic of conditionally excluding into something reusable. Is there a particular reason why you dont want to use a type?

Comment: @dx_over_dt I was experimenting a little, but I think this is not possible currently with only one interface. You will always need another type that modifies the original type in some way. I added a little paragraph at the end why I think it is not possible - Besides that is there a particular reason why you dont want to use a type?

Comment: Succinctness is really the only reason. DRY, ya know?

Comment: @dx_over_dt Yeah I understand, Well you don't need to repeat too much if you use my solution. Was thinking if maybe we could solve that issue on a "higher" level if you understand what I mean. But seems not like it